# Programatically get serial number of a digital certificate from a signed file?

Tags: digital-signature, serial-number

How can I programatically (python preferably or java) get the serial number of the digital certificate a file, say /users/myfile, is signed with? Manually, I can do this by:
Right click myfile > Properties > Digital signature > details > advanced tab > and here you find serial number.

thanks.

Comment: what format is the signature made in? Is it PKCS#7/CMS/CAdES, XMLDSig/XAdES, PDF/PAdES, Authenticode, other ?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for your question? If so, can you share it here?